# Passing optional arguments through a wrapper method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wrapper, link-to

I have the following wrapper method for `link_to`:

```
def link_to_with_current(text, link, condition, *args)
  current_class = condition ? 'current' : nil
  link_to text, link, :class => current_class, *args
end
```

When called with this sample:

```
link_to_with_current 'My Link', '/mylink.html', true, :id => 'mylink'
```

The following link is generated:

```
<a href="/mylink" class="current">My Link</a>
```

Why doesn't the ID show up?

Comment: I don't think you want to be using a splat for those arguments, I think you will be better off using a hash (such as `options={}`). Have a look at the source for `link_to` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to theIV's suggestion, I found a version that works:

```
def link_to_with_current(text, link, condition, *args)
  options = args.first || {}
  options[:class] = condition ? 'current' : nil
  link_to text, link, options
end
```